# cmake install DESTINATION not working on Linux

Tags: cmake

This is my `CMakeLists.txt`, it works correctly on Windows and installs the dll to `bin` and the lib to `.lib`.

```
add_library(test SHARED)

target_sources(test PRIVATE test.cpp)

install(TARGETS test ARCHIVE DESTINATION /home/user/cmake_test/out/lib)
install(TARGETS test RUNTIME DESTINATION /home/user/cmake_test/out/bin)
```

On Linux the `DESTINATION` seems to be ignored and cmake tries to install `test.so` to `/usr/local/lib/test.so`. I could use `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` but I can't see anything in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) that suggests that this approach shouldn't work on Linux.

I've tried cmake 16 from the Ubuntu 20.04 repos and the latest cmake 3.19.1. Make and Ninja builds both have the same behaviour.

Comment: Documentation for [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command explicitly says, that `RUNTIME` affects on `.dll`, but other shared libraries are classified as `LIBRARY`. Since you don't specify destination for that class, `.so` are installed into default `lib/` prefix.

Comment: Note, that using **absolute** paths in DESTINATION is not a good approach. Instead, specify `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` as `/home/user/cmake_test/out` and use `lib` for `ARCHIVE` and `bin` for `RUNTIME`. BTW, normal locations for `LIBRARY` is `lib`: Unlike to Windows, on Linux libraries needn't to be placed near the executables. Also, several "classes" (ARCHIVE, RUNTIME) could be specified in the single `install()` invocation.